# Routing with optional parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have the following routing config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Pages",
               url: "{PageName}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "GetPageByName" }
            );
```

I need to make changes in the website structure. I need to route the URLs below to '`pagesController`'. The parameter in both cases to be sent to  the controller is 'PageName':

```
http://domain.com/PageName/
http://domain.com/something/PageName
```

"something" is not necessary but can be added and have no effect.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
                routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "Pages",
                   url: "{something}/{PageName}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "GetPageByName" }
                );

                routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "Pages",
                   url: "{PageName}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "GetPageByName" }
                );
```

You have to define in that order and that route will map to `GetPageByName` action method in your `PagesController`

```
public ActionResult GetPageByName(string pageName)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to do it:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Pages",
               url: "{stringURL}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "GetPageByStringURL" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Pages2",
               url: "{x}/{stringURL}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "GetPageByStringURL" }
            );
```